# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient' with package installed

Tags: python, flask, google-calendar-api

I am building a basic web app with flask and deployed using the Google App Engine. I use Google's API to access calendar info. When I test this out locally, it works fine and I have no issues with dependencies, but when I deploy it I get a 500 Server Error. There's also a `HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>` error which I suspect has to do with whatever is causing the API to not be read in correctly. 
[Here's my `pip freeze` with all dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n6Gt.png):

```
appdirs==1.4.4
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
distlib==0.3.0
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.3
google-auth==1.15.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
httplib2==0.18.1
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.15.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.9
virtualenv==20.0.21
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

My requirements.txt consists of Flask, Werkzeug, and google-api-python-client.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be better to provide text information as a text. The question would be easier to be searched and answered by other users.

Comment: I pasted the dependencies in a code block! Thanks.

Comment: Figured this one out! Just had to paste that whole pip freeze in my requirements.txt!